# How to scroll to the Particular date in Mobile Application using Appium 2.0

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, appium, appium-android, appium-java

I need some help in automating the date picker in appium 2.0 using java selenium.

I'm trying to scroll to the date January 23 2023 from the below image view.

[date selector using scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4Lzb.png)

I have tried with below code but it is not working.

```
try {
            String scrollableList="android:id/numberpicker_input";
            String elementClassName="android.widget.EditText";
            String anyText="January";

            
              driver.findElement(AppiumBy.androidUIAutomator(
              "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().resourceId(\"" + scrollableList +
              "\")).getChildByText(" + "new UiSelector().className(\"" + elementClassName +
              "\"), \"" + anyText + "\")"));
             
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Cannot scroll further");
        }
```

Onething I need to inform here is resource-id and className is same for day-month-year.